assigning row median to NA values
I have this data set:
structure(list(V1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), V2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V4 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V5 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), V6 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), V7 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), V8 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), V9 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), V10 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), V11 = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), V12 = c(1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V13 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V14 = c(1, 
NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), V15 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), V16 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V17 = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V18 = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), V19 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V20 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")

How can I assign row values to NA by group == 1. (or we can consider the rows that contain NA).
There are 2 NAs. First one must be 0 (2nd row's mean = 0), second one must be 1 (33rd row's mean = 1).
Desired Output:


What if the row median is 0.5?

Often if we need to do some rowwise computations it means we need a matrix, or a long data frame. With any of those the performance and clarity of the code will usually be better.

Loop rowwise using apply and replace NA with median:
apply(data, 1, function(v){ v[ is.na(v) ] = median(v, na.rm = TRUE); v })


You have to transpose the result.
